# Что уже случилось не исправить

Tags: запятые

Можете сказать, пэры Вы да мастэры и мэтры любезные, куда правильно в данных предложениях поставить запятую?

1. Что уже случилось нельзя исправить.
2. Уже что случилось не исправить.

Comment: @Буратино Чего это?

Comment: @oleedd не знаю, так показалось) не прав?

Comment: @Буратино Абсолютно. Если придаточное можно переставить... Вспоминаем правило.

Comment: @oleedd мне кажется есть разница между: случилось то, что нельзя исправить и случилось и нельзя исправить. Что случилось - подлежащие)

Comment: @Буратино Не понял. Просто меняем порядок. Ничего больше менять нельзя.

Comment: @oleedd ну вы считаете, что "что" - подлежащие, а случилось - сказуемое, а я считаю "что случилось" - это подлежащие. Случившееся нельзя исправить. То есть это не логическое рассуждение, а утверждение.

Comment: @Буратино Дело в том, что "что" — это подчинительный союз / союзное слово. Нельзя считать придаточное предложение подлежащим.

Comment: Что не союз, а местоимение в связке с глаголом, дает подлежащие) - это случилось нельзя исправить-> случившееся нельзя исправить. Это случилось не совсем то, потому что "что" дает какую-то подчиненность, но не придаточному, а самому глаголу. Что случилось = случившееся.

Comment: @Буратино Разная грамматика, и разное оформление. Подлежащим такое не считают, но да, похоже.

Comment: @oleedd ну стандартно не считают, но зависит же от интонации. Если это логический вывод - то союз, а если вывода нет, а фраза звучит как утверждение того "что случилось", то это не союз уже.

Comment: @Буратино В данном случае союзное слово. Ср.: *Купил, что мне понравилось. Купил мне понравившееся.*

Comment: @oleedd Это другое, здесь нет "что". Что купилось мне нравится, а тебе?

Comment: @Буратино Да такое же. Короче, запятые в таких случаях тоже ставятся. Так как есть придаточные предложения.

Answer (score 3):

Я бы так записала (по слуху):

*1. Что уже случилось, исправить нельзя.*

*2. Что уже случилось – не исправить.*

**Порядок слов** не менее важен, чем знаки. Не стоит считать, что в русском языке свободный порядок слов. От него зависит многое: как смысл сказанного,  так и корректное чтение и расстановка пауз и ударений.

**Выбор тире** во втором предложении связан с разной структурой его частей.

Comment: А чего второй вариант другой? Там "уже" в начале.

Comment: Уже прочитали?..

Comment: (1) Порядок слов изменен.  (2) Ничего я не читала, времени нет.  Там буковок, наверное, много.

Comment: 1. Порядок слов менять нельзя. Представьте, что вы на ЕГЭ. Автора интересует пунктуация именно при таком порядке. 2. Не много.

Comment: Это вам нельзя, а мне можно. А почему – я написала.  При таком порядке некорректная стилистика, знаки уже ничего не изменят.

Comment: Стилистика корректная. Так тоже можно сказать. Автора интересует пунктуация в "уже, что", иначе бы не было второго варианта. Только вы здесь примеры меняете.

Comment: Ну, я не знала, что интересует автора. Хотела его порадовать интересным решением.

Comment: Вот это правило: Не выделяются запятыми приложения, характеризующие предмет с какой-либо одной стороны. Например: *Карл Маркс высоко ценил Чернышевского как философа и публициста. Горького как писателя знает весь мир. Эффект многолетних трав как восстановителей плодородия почв ничтожно мал.* Если не очень понятно, то вы знаете, где найти мои объяснения. Знали об этом? И здесь дело не в ударениях, они — просто следствие.

Comment: Ну так что? Сколько можно спрашивать?

Comment: Ничего не поняла. Про "с какой-либо одной стороны" каждый школьник знает, ну и я тоже знаю. Так что спасибо, давайте закроем тему.

Comment: Вот, это часто в школе используется. Но никто здесь об этом не говорил. Вы столько про обороты с "как" рассказывали, но у вас ни разу такого не видел. И в электронном справочнике нет, и у Лопатина вроде бы тоже. А к чему тогда "Ничего не поняла"?

Answer (score 0):

Если бы предложение было таким: ‟То, что уже случилось, не исправить”, то пунктуация была бы очевидной – ‟что уже случилось” – это просто определительное придаточное, которое обособляется. Тут просто человек нарушил норму использования местоимения ‟то”, а мы тут сидим и думаем, что тут поставить. Просто поставьте запятую перед ‟не исправить”, как если бы это ‟то” тут было. Назовём это пропущенным словом в неполном предложении. В итоге: **‟Что уже случилось, не исправить”.**

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146265/discussion-on-answer-by-jim-korbett-----); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Comment: Ещё пример, получше: *Он как боксёр не имеет себе равных.* Не имеет равных в боксе, а если рассматривать другое, то равные есть.

Comment: Так что добавляйте новый пункт в свой справочник.

Comment: Как только увижу в этом крупицу смысла, тогда сразу добавлю.

Comment: Так часто пишут. Это характерно даже для научного стиля. Отступления в таких случаях не делаются.

Comment: Sharon сказала, что об этом каждый школьник знает. Мне со школы известно...

Answer (score 0):

В общем, дело обстоит примерно так:

Если это логическое рассуждение и "что" является союзом, то по дефолту нужно ставить запятую, так как логическое умозаключение(ну или тире).

Что уже случилось, нельзя исправить.

Однако, если считать, что слово "что" - это не союз, а местоимение, то, вероятно, в связке с глаголом оно будет подлежащим "что случилось" - "случившееся". Случившееся нельзя исправить - запятая не нужна.

Насчет второго. Постановка *уже* и *что* - специфическая, скорее всего *уже* здесь наречие не относящееся к первой части, так что нужна запятая после: *уже, что случилось нельзя исправить*. И я бы склонялся к этому варианту из-за вводного, либо как-то так:
*Уже. Что случилось нельзя исправить.*/ Уже(вот оно)! Что случилось не исправить (случившееся не исправить)!

Или так: *и что случилось не исправить*. То есть, если есть целостность, можно вставить "и" в начале - запятая не нужна.

Однако, мои рассуждения могут быть в корне не верны, так что особо не рассчитывайте на их правильность)

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146264/discussion-on-answer-by------); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.